# I need to implement a functionality to use thermal printer in angular app. I tried unfortunately didn't get success

Tags: npm, printing, dependencies, angular6, thermal-printer

I am using **ng-thermal-print** but getting some error.
version of dependecies
angualar : 6
ng-thermal-print: 0.1.5

package.json

```
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
"@angular/cli": "~6.1.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "6.1.0",
"@angular/fire": "^5.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ApiService } from "../../services/api.service";
import { PrintService, UsbDriver, WebPrintDriver } from "ng-thermal-print";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnDestroy {
  status: boolean = false;
  usbPrintDriver: UsbDriver;
  webPrintDriver: WebPrintDriver;
  ip: string = "";

  public constructor(
    public api: ApiService,
    private printService: PrintService
  ) {
    this.usbPrintDriver = new UsbDriver();
    this.printService.isConnected.subscribe((result) => {
      this.status = result;
      if (result) {
        console.log("Connected to printer!!!");
      } else {
        console.log("Not connected to printer.");
      }
    });
  }

  requestUsb() {
    this.usbPrintDriver.requestUsb().subscribe((result) => {
      this.printService.setDriver(this.usbPrintDriver, "ESC/POS");
    });
  }

  connectToWebPrint() {
    this.webPrintDriver = new WebPrintDriver(this.ip);
    this.printService.setDriver(this.webPrintDriver, "WebPRNT");
  }

  print(data) {
    this.printService
      .init()
      .setBold(true)
      .writeLine("Hello World")
      .setBold(false)
      .feed(4)
      .cut("full")
      .flush();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Print Order</button>
```

I am getting some error like **Object(...) is not a function**
I have installed **@types/w3c-web-usb** for usb detection

I attached image of error.
[image: error message]
Please help me